# Generate code snippets not work for some languages

Tags: postman

Postman can generate code for some languages, such as go/curl/HTTP - This seems to not work for python/java, If I click Python, nothing happens!

I checked the dev tools and no errors were seen in the console.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking in the same way, how Postman can be released their product with such an issue! I then searched a bit more, and found the secret :)

*Hint: right side arrows indicates something!*

[image]

Comment: On the latest 7.6.0 version, If you go to *settings > General* you can toggle on the `new code gen UI` which has a bunch of new features and fixes in it.

Comment: It should be it that version too, that was the version on Canary / getting released this week 

Comment: I see, but [this is kinda interesting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stgST.gif)

Comment: Have you tried quitting the app and trying it again?

Comment: Yes, started it again and it's now updated. Thanks! @DannyDainton